# Computing the complement of a set

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, time-complexity, sorting, finite-sets

Suppose I have a set $A$ of elements in $\{1, \ldots, n\}$, given as an unordered list. 
I would like to compute the complement of $A$, i.e., I would like to produce an unordered list of entries in $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ but not in $A$.

One way to do this is to sort the entries of $A$ and then go through them and list all the entries I do not see. This takes $O(n \log n)$ in the unit cost RAM model. My question is whether there exists a linear time $O(n)$ algorithm in the same model.

Comment: Actually, the sorting can be faster than that; [see](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~plaisted/comp550/linear%20time%20sorting.pdf) [these](http://www.ijcaonline.org/volume24/number3/pxc3873876.pdf) [four](http://web.mit.edu/benmv/Public/thorup.pdf) [papers](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-319-08404-6_3). $\;$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you have both lists, even if not both at the same time, your
space cost is at least that of the longest, thus at least $n/2$.
This corresponds to a $O(n)$ space complexity.

So, unless you exclude it for some reason, it makes sense to use a bit
array $M[1:n]$ to represent the set A by its characteristic function,
i.e. $M[i]=0$ iff $i\notin A$, and $1$ otherwise. The space complexity
is unchanged, and the array $M$ is actually much smaller than one of
the two lists (initial or final).

Initializing the array $M$ from the initial list is linear.

Then you can take the logical complement of the array $M$ in linear
time.

Then you scan the array in linear time to get all the element of the
complement of your initial list in linear time $O(n)$

Of course, by now you have noticed your mistake: sorting is in time
$O(n \log n)$ (or better according to comment) when $n$ is the number
of element to be sorted.  But it is trivially linear if $n$ is the size of the
finite ordered set they come from.

Using an array, as I just did is one way of sorting in linear time with respect to the size of the referance set.

**Your own answer was good** because of that. Only your complexity assessment was wrong.